# ModuleNotFoundError when running a file inside a __init__ folder

Tags: python

Tree

/src/_*init*_.py 
/src/logger.py 
/src/util.py 
main.py 
__init__.py

When running `main.py` I use the syntax `from src.logger import *`
Inside `/src/logger.py` I use `from src.util import *`

This works fine when running `main.py`, the problem occurs when i've tried running `/src/logger.py`.
This results in Error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

if I change `/src/logger.py` to `from util import *` I can run without error, but `main.py` results in Error

```
File "c:\Apps\POC OEC\src\logger.py", line 5, in <module>
    from util import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'
```

Comment: Did you try ```from .util import *```?

Comment: @ewokx i tried but results in error when running `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: You need `__init__.py` in the root directory too.

Comment: @andyhasit i created the `__init__.py` on the same level as `main.py` but i've got the same error when running `logger.py`: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

Comment: When running `python src/logger.py` from the root dir, and with `from src.util import *` in logger.py?

Comment: Actually I think you will need to run it like so: `python -m src.logger`

Comment: @andyhasit `python -m src.logger` this worked as expected. Can you create a Answer with that so I can Accept it as a Answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need `__init__.py` in the root directory as well as in `src`.

Then run your code as a module using `-m` option, like so:

```
python -m src.logger
```

When running this way make sure you specify the module path `src.logger` rather than the file path `src/logger.py`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, import paths are always relative to the directory where you run the Python interpreter, so for both `main.py` and `src/logger.py` to work, they both have to specify `util` as `src.util`:

```
from src.util import *
```

And you have to run the interpreter from where `main.py` is. That is, run `logger.py` with:

```
> python src/logger.py
```

Comment: `> python src/logger.py` unfortunately still results in the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`.